# PHP выполнение функции при условии

Tags: php, if, foreach

```
$item = 'item'
if ($a == 1) {
    foreach ($b as $i => $item) { //открывается цикл
}//закрытие IF
    echo $item;

if ($a == 1) {
} //закрывается цикл
}


немого добавил инфы..
в определенных случаях на странице не нужно запускать данный цикл (просто нету массива данных для обработки)
дабы не делать копии одной и той же страницы для двух разных сценариев
```

Comment: Просто оберните весь цикл в `if()`

Comment: у вас условие одно и тоже сейчвас....... в чём вопрос заключается и что за задача?

Comment: $item = 'item'
if ($a == 'edit')
    foreach ($b as $i => $item) { //открывается цикл
    }
    echo $item;

if ($a == 'edit') {
} //закрывается цикл
}
немого добавил инфы..
в определенных случаях на странице не нужно запускать данный цикл (просто нету массива данных для обработки)
дабы не делать копии одной и той же страницы для двух разных сценариев

Comment: `if ($a == 1) { цикл с выводом } else { echo $item; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$a    = 1;
$item = 'item';
$b    = [1, 2, 4, 5];

if ($a == 1) {
    foreach ($b as $i => $item) {
        echo $item;
    }
} else {
    echo $item;
}
```

Comment: В данном примере $item будет выводиться только при условии $a = 1. У меня же задача - вывод $item в любом случае, но если $a = 1, то тогда $item  будет результатом вывода из данных массива и цикла

Comment: @CaHeKLast изменил ответ. А задачу лучше поточнее описывать.

Comment: В задаче полностью описано действие которое требуется, такое решение увы не подходит. В php я так понимаю невозможно при условии включить цикл при определенном условии, а если это условие не выполняется, то просто пропустить foreach
 if ($a == 1) {
    foreach ($b as $i => $item) { //открывается цикл
}//закрытие IF

Comment: @CaHeKLast в задаче синтаксические ошибки и поставлена она криво. Исправил ответ.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте
If endif;
Foreach endforeach;

Comment: Не работает, ошибка синтаксиса, уже испытано

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]